# Multiple DHCP range on CoovaChilli

Tags: ip, range, dhcp, coovachilli

I'm trying to get working CoovaChilli under multiple subclasses.

for example i want to build something like:

```
192.168.182.1-254
192.168.183.1-254
```

to extend connections on device.

There's no too much documentation for it but what i found is not relevant and not working.

Interesting links:

https://www.linuxmuster.net/wiki/anwenderwiki:benutzerrechner:wlan:coovachilli-dhcp

If someone had same problem and solved it please post it here.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After briefly looking into the https://github.com/coova/coova-chilli it looks for me like multiple dhcp ranges probably is not supported.

In such case I would go for configuring dedicated local B class - ie. `172.x.0.0/16` (x in range 16-31) or anything having mask of more than 8 bits.